# Is it okay for a Muslim girl not to have children?

Tags: halal-haram, women, children

I was wondering if it was okay for a Muslim girl not to have children if she didn't want any?

I'm a Muslim young lady and I like children, I just don't know if I actually want any children because I'm scared of child birth.

Answer (score 0):

You can delay your pregnancy but you shouldn't think that way at all..

You can take your time to be able to hold the situation, but you can't say I don't want children.

children are grace of ALLAH and we shouldn't refuse this gift.

I'm gonna ask you a question and you'll got what I want to tell you. Forget about fatwa and hadeeth and Islam at all.

If your president give you a gift, do you dare to say him I don't want it?!!!!
 I'm sure you'll never do it(me too!!)... So if you do that wit a president! I think its better and worthy to never refuse His gifts and grace..

I advise you just take your time and make yourself get to be a mom. It's the best thing you'll ever have.. This time try to get used to the idea, read books and ask others to help.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's your body and your life, so you can decide whatever you want to do with them.

If you are already pregnant maybe you should consider more carefully what to do. Some people say abortion is haram at all stages. Others think that it's okay the first trimester. It's really up to you.

If you are not pregnant, then, nobody is forcing you to have kids. You will be judged on the basis of what good deeds you have done in your life. Having children is not a good deed in itself if you don't take care of them once you make them. (I'm not saying you wouldn't take care of them, but if you don't want to have kids there is a possibility that you are going to dislike being a mother).

Also, there is always the option of adoption. Not only you would have a kid (since you said you like kids but you are only scared of child birth), but you would also do a good deed, saving a little orphan.